# Substitute value of an attribute based on conditions in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, conditional-statements

I am working on an API module in scala which queries DB and returns the fetched data in JSON format as the response.
For a particular attribute in the JSON(whose type is `Option[String]`) , I need to alter the value fetched from DB based on certain conditions.
Currently , my JSON response looks like this:

```
.....
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "osType": "windows",        
    "osVersion": "10.0.14393"        
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz",
    "osType": "ubuntu",        
    "osVersion": "18.04"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "pqr",
    "osType": "windows",        
    "osVersion": "6.1.7601"
},
......
```

I need to substitute the following values for `osVersion` for records with  `"osType": "windows"`

```
if osVersion = 10.0.14393 , then Windows Server 2016
if osVersion starts with 6.1 , then Windows Server 2008 R2
```

So that desired output looks like this:

```
.....
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "osType": "windows",        
    "osVersion": "Windows Server 2016"        
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz",
    "osType": "ubuntu",        
    "osVersion": "18.04"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "pqr",
    "osType": "windows",        
    "osVersion": "Windows Server 2008 R2"
},
......
```

I tried using `if-else` and `pattern-matching` , but am unable to substitute correctly as the type is `Option[String]`.
This is how I tried:
(1)

```
def translateOSVersion (osType :Option[String] ,osVersion : Option[String]):Option[String] ={
          if (osType == "windows"){
            val version = if (osVersion =="10.0.14393")
              {
                Some("Windows Server 2016")
              }
            else {osVersion}
            version
            }
        }

        val oSVersion = translateOSVersion(ostr("osType") ,ostr("osVersion") )

        <modelJSON>(id, name, ostr("osType"), oSVersion)
```

(2)

```
 def translateOSVersion (osType :Option[String] ,osVersion : Option[String]) ={
  if (osType == "windows"){
    val version = if (osVersion =="10.0.14393") Some("Windows Server 2016")
    else osVersion
    }
}

val oSVersion = Some(translateOSVersion(ostr("osType") ,ostr("osVersion") ).toString)
  <modelJSON>(id, name, ostr("osType"), oSVersion)
```

(3)

```
def translateOSVersion (osType :Option[String] ,osVersion : Option[String]) ={
      if (osType == "windows"){
        osVersion match {
          case Some("10.0.14393") => "Windows Server 2016"
          case x =>x
        }
        }
    }
val oSVersion = Some(translateOSVersion(ostr("osType") ,ostr("osVersion") ).toString)
      <modelJSON>(id, name, ostr("osType"), oSVersion)
```

All the approaches do not result in desired result.
Kindly help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def translateOSVersion(osType: Option[String], osVersion: Option[String]): Option[String] =
  (for {
    ot <- osType if ot == "windows"
    ov <- osVersion
  } yield {
    if (ov == "10.0.14393") {
      "Windows Server 2016"
    } else if (ov.startsWith("6.1")) {
      "Windows Server 2008 R2"
    } else {
      ov
    }
  }) orElse osVersion
```

This is how it works:

The `for` statement creates a new `Option[String]` representing the updated version number, or `None` if there is no change. It works by extracting the two `Option` values into `ot` for the OS Type and `ov` for the OS Version. If either of the `Option`s is `None` it will return `None`, and it will also return `None` if the OS type is not "windows". If all these tests pass, the `yield` expression computes the new version based on these values. In this case the `for` will return `Some(x)` where `x` is the value of the `yield` expression.

The `orElse` expression will return the first value if it is `Some(x)`, otherwise it will return the second value. So if the result of the `for` is `Some(x)` then it is returned as the result of the function. If the `for` returns `None` then the original value is returned as the result.

---

This is a more prosaic version that is probably more suitable, though less fun!

```
def translateOSVersion(osType: Option[String], osVersion: Option[String]): Option[String] =
  if (osType.contains("windows")) {
    if (osVersion.contains("10.0.14393")) {
      Some("Windows Server 2016")
    } else if (osVersion.exists(_.startsWith("6.1"))) {
      Some("Windows Server 2008 R2")
    } else {
      osVersion
    }
  } else {
    osVersion
  }
```